# Random screen freeze on new Ubuntu 18.04LTS install on old MacBook Pro

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, freeze, macbook

I have (like many) installed Ubuntu to try and squeeze more life out of my old `Macbook Pro`. After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I now have a couple of problems (I'm not sure if they are related or not):

1) After I login with my password and press enter I'm faced with a bizarre pixelated screen for around 4 seconds. I've just taken a photo from my phone:

[image: Weird pixelated black and white screen]

2) After web-browsing and then leaving my laptop for say 30 seconds or so the screen would simply go black and I could not seem to wake it up from this suspend. The only thing I could do was to do a hard shut-down (just hold my power button down until it turned off).

After this I did a search on what could possibly be the issue here and tried the following at the terminal:

`sudo apt install gnome-screensaver`

After this I did seem to get around Problem 2 above (not waking from the suspend). After being lulled into a false sense of security I installed `PyCharm` - the only thing I have done apart from web browsing after this brand new install. However, now Ubuntu just freezes randomly. For example, after I installed and then ran `PyCharm` (I had a terminal open at the time and a web-browser) the screen froze. I could move my cursor but nothing I clicked on the screen would respond.

Not sure if I'm asking too much from a rather old computer or what the problem is. Would really love to have Ubuntu working on this laptop though.

I'm quite stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, not even sure if this is something I can fix or if it is a bug I have to file...

Cheers,
Sandy

Comment: I can't really help with an actual answer, but Macs are a little notorious for not offering the best user experience with Linux. A lot of closed-cource drivers. Out of curiosity, how old was the MBP? My 2015 one runs Ubuntu 18.04 OK, but I always have issues with the HiDPI Retina display and scaling, especially when combined with external monitors.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks for trying to help. It is a MacBook Pro Unibody 17" A1297 - Late 2011. Which is of course, when I think about it, super-old. I may be being a little optimistic. Haven't tried it with an external monitor.